# How to get the TLS client supported TLS versions in python ssl

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, tls1.2

In python ssl, one can configure the TLS client's ciphersuites and versions. The ciphersuites are set using  `context.set_ciphers(ciphers)` and the versions using `context.options`.

To make sure from the setup, one can get the ciphers in a client (even before the handshake, this is for setting up the client) using `context.get_ciphers()`.

My question: how can I get the client's supported protocols. Please note that I am not using the default versions. I changed them by excluding some versions using `context.options`. For example, this statement excludes TLS 1.1 from my client:

```
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
```

I want to make sure form my client TLS versions in the same way as I did in the ciphers using `context.get_ciphers()`. Is there any way I can do so?

Comment: Who is the client? Are you the server? If you are, the connection already took place (and the handshake was done - meaning that the server and client found a *TLS* protocol version (and other stuff) that both support). `context.get_ciphers()` what is `context`?  Cause if it's an `ssl.SSLContext` object, it doesn't have a `get_ciphers()` method.

Comment: @CristiFati  I am the client. The `get_cipehrs()` shows me the clinet's ciphers. But I am looking for something similar that shows me the clinet's versions. I could not find.

Comment: I was testing on *Python3.5* where there's no `get_ciphers()`. You have to write that functionality on your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functionality you're after is available (at least partially) in *Python 3.**6*** (and newer). Check [[Python 3]: ssl - TLS/SSL wrapper for socket objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) for more details:

> ```py
> >>> import sys
> >>> import ssl
> >>> "Python {:s} on {:s}".format(sys.version, sys.platform)
> 'Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32'
> >>> ctx0 = ssl.create_default_context()
> >>> ctx0.options
> <Options.OP_NO_SSLv3|OP_NO_SSLv2|OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE|OP_SINGLE_DH_USE|OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE|OP_NO_COMPRESSION|OP_ALL: -2091252737>
> ```

For older versions, some code (which also works on newer ones) is required.

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import ssl
from pprint import pprint as pp


__PROTO_TAG = "PROTOCOL_"
__OP_NO_TAG = "OP_NO_"
__OP_NO_TAG_LEN = len(__OP_NO_TAG)
_PROTOS_DATA = list()
for item_name in dir(ssl):
    if item_name.startswith(__OP_NO_TAG) and item_name[-1].isdigit():  # item_name[-1].isdigit() condition is required because protocol denial (OP_NO_*) constants end in digit(s) (version); therefore constants like OP_NO_TICKET are excluded
        op_no_item = getattr(ssl, item_name)
        if op_no_item:
            proto_name = item_name[__OP_NO_TAG_LEN:]
            _PROTOS_DATA.append((proto_name, getattr(ssl, __PROTO_TAG + proto_name, -1), op_no_item))
del __OP_NO_TAG_LEN
del __OP_NO_TAG
del __PROTO_TAG


def get_protocols(ctx):
    supported_classes = (ssl.SSLContext,)
    if not isinstance(ctx, supported_classes):
        raise TypeError("Argument must be an instance of `{:}`".format(supported_classes[0] if len(supported_classes) == 1 else supported_classes))
    protocols = list()
    for proto_data in _PROTOS_DATA:
        if ctx.options & proto_data[-1] != proto_data[-1]:
            protocols.append(proto_data[:-1])
    return protocols


def print_data(ctx):
    print("Options: {:08X} ({!r})".format(ctx.options, ctx.options))
    print("Protocols:")
    for proto in get_protocols(ctx):
        print("    {:s} - {:d}".format(*proto))
    print()


def main():
    print("{:s}\n".format(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION))
    ctx0 = ssl.create_default_context()
    print_data(ctx0)
    print("--- Removing TLSv1_1...")
    ctx0.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
    print_data(ctx0)
    print("--- Adding SSLv3...")
    ctx0.options -= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3  # !!! N.B.: Due to the fact that ssl.OP_NO_* flags only have one bit set, this works, but DON'T DO IT !!!
    print_data(ctx0)
    print("\nComputed protocols:")
    pp([item[:-1] + (hex(item[-1]),) for item in _PROTOS_DATA])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- As I worked extensively in this area, I have lots of *Python* versions on a variety of *OS*es, built against various *OpenSSL* versions (as seen in the outputs below)
- Tried to keep everything as general as possible
- Basing the code on (*ssl*) module attributes only; due to the fact that each *Python* version is built with a particular *OpenSSL* version, surprises might arise when using custom combinations (I could hardcode the *OP_NO_** constants - which are consistent over *OpenSSL* versions, but that wouldn't be scalable)
- There is the *ssl* module implementation (specific to *Python* version, which relies on a specific *OpenSSL* version - as stated above), plus the *OpenSSL* version (which might might not have some stuff) actually used to build the *ssl* module. That's why running the same code on various combinations, yields (slightly) **different** results (check outputs below)
- On *Win* things are simpler, as (by default) *OpenSSL* is **statically** linked in *_ssl.pyd* (starting with *Python 3.**7***, this **no longer applies**, the *OpenSSL* *.dll*s are also shipped as part of *Python*), but on *Nix*, the *OpenSSL* libs (that are installed on the system) are loaded at runtime
- Code walkthrough:

  - *_PROTOS_DATA* - computed at module import time: it's a list of protocol entries, based on *ssl* module attributes. Each entry has 3 fields:

    - Protocol name
    - Protocol identifier in the  *ssl* module (***-1*** if not present: e.g. *SSLv2*)
    - The *OP_NO_* constant used to disable this protocol

    It's displayed at the end of each run for clarity
  - *get_protocols* - determines the "active" supported protocols for an `ssl.SSLContext`
  - *print_data* - helper function

**Output**:

- *Win 10 x64*

  > ```py
  > e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049788677>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe" code.py
  > Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
  >
  > OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
  >
  > Options: -7CA5FC01 (<Options.OP_NO_SSLv3|OP_NO_SSLv2|OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE|OP_SINGLE_DH_USE|OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE|OP_NO_COMPRESSION|OP_ALL: -2091252737>)
  > Protocols:
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_1 - 4
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  >
  > --- Removing TLSv1_1...
  > Options: -6CA5FC01 (<Options.OP_NO_TLSv1_1|OP_NO_SSLv3|OP_NO_SSLv2|OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE|OP_SINGLE_DH_USE|OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE|OP_NO_COMPRESSION|OP_ALL: -1822817281>)
  > Protocols:
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  >
  > --- Adding SSLv3...
  > Options: -6EA5FC01 (<Options.OP_NO_TLSv1_1|OP_NO_SSLv2|OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE|OP_SINGLE_DH_USE|OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE|OP_NO_COMPRESSION|OP_ALL: -1856371713>)
  > Protocols:
  >     SSLv3 - 1
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  >
  >
  > Computed protocols:
  > [('SSLv2', -1, '0x1000000'),
  >  ('SSLv3', <_SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_SSLv3: 1>, '0x2000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1', <_SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLSv1: 3>, '0x4000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1_1', <_SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1: 4>, '0x10000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1_2', <_SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2: 5>, '0x8000000')]
  >
  > e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049788677>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py34x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
  > Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
  >
  > OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
  >
  > Options: -7CFDFC01 (-2097019905)
  > Protocols:
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_1 - 4
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  >
  > --- Removing TLSv1_1...
  > Options: -6CFDFC01 (-1828584449)
  > Protocols:
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  >
  > --- Adding SSLv3...
  > Options: -6EFDFC01 (-1862138881)
  > Protocols:
  >     SSLv3 - 1
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  >
  >
  > Computed protocols:
  > [('SSLv2', 0, '0x1000000'),
  >  ('SSLv3', 1, '0x2000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1', 3, '0x4000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1_1', 4, '0x10000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1_2', 5, '0x8000000')]
  >
  > e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049788677>"c:\Install\x64\Python\Python\3.7\python.exe" code.py
  > Python 3.7.0b4 (v3.7.0b4:eb96c37699, May  2 2018, 19:02:22) [MSC v.1913 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
  >
  > OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018
  >
  > Options: -7DBDFFAC (<Options.OP_NO_SSLv3|OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE|OP_NO_COMPRESSION|OP_ALL: -2109603756>)
  > Protocols:
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_1 - 4
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  >
  > --- Removing TLSv1_1...
  > Options: -6DBDFFAC (<Options.OP_NO_TLSv1_1|OP_NO_SSLv3|OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE|OP_NO_COMPRESSION|OP_ALL: -1841168300>)
  > Protocols:
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  >
  > --- Adding SSLv3...
  > Options: -6FBDFFAC (<Options.OP_NO_TLSv1_1|OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE|OP_NO_COMPRESSION|OP_ALL: -1874722732>)
  > Protocols:
  >     SSLv3 - -1
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  >
  >
  > Computed protocols:
  > [('SSLv3', -1, '0x2000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1', <_SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLSv1: 3>, '0x4000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1_1', <_SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1: 4>, '0x10000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1_2', <_SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2: 5>, '0x8000000')]
  > ```
- *OSX 9 x64*:

  > ```py
  > cfati@cfati-macosx9x64-1:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q049788677]> python code.py
  > Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 05:51:29)
  > [GCC 4.8.2] on darwin
  >
  > OpenSSL 1.0.1p-fips 9 Jul 2015
  >
  > Options: 830203FF (2197947391L)
  > Protocols:
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_1 - 4
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  > ()
  > --- Removing TLSv1_1...
  > Options: 930203FF (2466382847L)
  > Protocols:
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  > ()
  > --- Adding SSLv3...
  > Options: 910203FF (2432828415L)
  > Protocols:
  >     SSLv3 - 1
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  > ()
  >
  > Computed protocols:
  > [('SSLv2', 0, '0x1000000'),
  >  ('SSLv3', 1, '0x2000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1', 3, '0x4000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1_1', 4, '0x10000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1_2', 5, '0x8000000')]
  > ```
- *Ubtu 16 x64*:

  > ```py
  > [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q049788677]> python3 code.py
  > Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
  > [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
  >
  > OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
  >
  > Options: 830203FF (2197947391)
  > Protocols:
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_1 - 4
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  >
  > --- Removing TLSv1_1...
  > Options: 930203FF (2466382847)
  > Protocols:
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  >
  > --- Adding SSLv3...
  > Options: 930203FF (2466382847)
  > Protocols:
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  >
  >
  > Computed protocols:
  > [('SSLv2', -1, '0x1000000'),
  >  ('SSLv3', -1, '0x2000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1', <_SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLSv1: 3>, '0x4000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1_1', <_SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1: 4>, '0x10000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1_2', <_SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2: 5>, '0x8000000')]
  > [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q049788677]>
  > [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q049788677]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../q049493537/Python-3.6.4:../q049320993/ssl/build/lib ../q049493537/Python-3.6.4/python code.py
  > Python 3.6.4 (default, Mar 28 2018, 23:34:25)
  > [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
  >
  > OpenSSL 1.0.2h-fips  3 May 2016
  >
  > Options: 835A03FF (<Options.OP_ALL|OP_NO_SSLv3|OP_NO_SSLv2|OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE|OP_SINGLE_DH_USE|OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE|OP_NO_COMPRESSION: 2203714559>)
  > Protocols:
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_1 - 4
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  >
  > --- Removing TLSv1_1...
  > Options: 935A03FF (<Options.OP_ALL|OP_NO_TLSv1_1|OP_NO_SSLv3|OP_NO_SSLv2|OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE|OP_SINGLE_DH_USE|OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE|OP_NO_COMPRESSION: 2472150015>)
  > Protocols:
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  >
  > --- Adding SSLv3...
  > Options: 915A03FF (<Options.OP_ALL|OP_NO_TLSv1_1|OP_NO_SSLv2|OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE|OP_SINGLE_DH_USE|OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE|OP_NO_COMPRESSION: 2438595583>)
  > Protocols:
  >     SSLv3 - -1
  >     TLSv1 - 3
  >     TLSv1_2 - 5
  >
  >
  > Computed protocols:
  > [('SSLv2', -1, '0x1000000'),
  >  ('SSLv3', -1, '0x2000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1', <_SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLSv1: 3>, '0x4000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1_1', <_SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1: 4>, '0x10000000'),
  >  ('TLSv1_2', <_SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2: 5>, '0x8000000')]
  > ```